# Double-Checked Locking - does it work in Java on earth?

Tags: java, multithreading, singleton

all:

Here is the famous article:

[The "Double-Checked Locking is Broken" Declaration](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html)

It declares that pattern doesn't work in Java. It further says, close to the end, that new JVM can make the pattern work by using volatile.

However, in another article: [Memory Barriers and JVM Concurrency](http://www.infoq.com/articles/memory_barriers_jvm_concurrency)

It says keyword "synchronized" generates memory barrier full fences. So who is right? Does the pattern work in Java on earth?

Comment: It should be noted that "new JVM" in that article is the one in Java 5: so yes, all current (non-ancient) JVMs *can* use the pattern *if* implemented correctly (using `volatile`).

Comment: See if you can grab a copy of Josh Bloch's 'Java Concurrency in Practice'. It explains why *it works in Java >=1.5* and what had to change in the J. memory model. It also contains an alternative to the double-checked locking idiom.

Comment: The second article you link to seems to look at *one specific implementation*: it's entirely possible that double-check *works* on one architecture (in one JDK, with one particular set of settings) and *still* be broken in general (because it's not guaranteed to work in a conforming JVM).

Comment: The whole point of DCL is to *avoid* `synchronized`. Sure, `synchronized` works and generates full fences, but that defeats the whole point of DCL -- to avoid having a full fence on every access to the object. It happens to work on the old JVM but is not guaranteed to work and thus very foolish to use. It works, by design and according to the specifications, on the new JVM, with `volatile`, as explained in the article.

Comment: Is there a place of comprehensive explanation about memory barrier and volatile? All information I get on internet are scattered. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've put a bit more info below, but really if your grand plan to improve performance is to scrat around to remove memory fences by using "techniques" such as double-checked locking, that's God's way of telling you that your architecture is more fundamentally broken. Use the properly implemented, fully tested concurrency libraries provided by the platform if there is actually a problem to solve...

Comment: And if you actually have some profiling data showing that you have a problem that would be solvable with DCL, please share it: it'll probably be the first such data every actually published.

Comment: Is the "Singleton" tag intentional?  Kinda changes the nature of the question.

Answer (score 4):

There are essentially 3 ways to fix double-checked locking:

- ensure that the variable is declared **volatile** (works from Java 5 onwards);
- just **don't bother with it** in the first place: just use synchronization and don't try to mess around with fancy bug-prone-- and probably pointless-- means of "avoiding" it;
- let the **classloader** do the synchronization for you.

I've posted [example code here](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/double_checked_locking_fixing.shtml).

**BUT:** Double-checked locking is really an outdated paradigm, if indeed it was ever useful in Java. As I see things, it was essentially carried over into Java by C programmers who didn't fully appreciate that the JVM effectively has a more efficient (and correct!) way of dealing with the issue built into the classloader and that optimisations to synchronization are generally best made at the JVM level.

I've seen a lot of people clutter their code with this "pattern". I don't think I've ever seen any actual data showing that it has any benefit.

Plus: if you do have a large application that is hitting synchronization issues, then one of the whole *raisons d'être* of Java is that it has rich concurrency libraries. Look at how you can re-work your application to use them... if profiling data proves it to be necessary.

Comment: +1 for suggesting concurrency-bodges as, at best, a possible optimization and not to be used during debugging.  It's bad enough getting stuff to work as it is without any nagging doubts about synchro.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what version of java you are using. 
This has been fixed in java 5 and forward.

Check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking#Usage_in_Java

Comment: Thanks. In the wiki article, it uses a local variable 'result' but doesn't explain the reason. Anyone knows answer? Thank you.

Comment: It's explained right under the code block:

"Note the usage of the local variable result which seems unnecessary. For some versions of the Java VM, it will make the code 25% faster and for others, it won't hurt."

Comment: @Sheen: every reference to `helper` requires reading from or writing to main memory. Register or cache is no good. Also, this access blocks the usual code-rearranging optimizations. Having `result` on the return saves one such awkward access. If `helper` is rarely null, it has to save at _least_ 25% on all but the most primitive machines.  __Also__, outside of the synch block (and maybe inside it) `helper` can change value at any time.  Returning value of `helper` could return an otherwise impossible null.

Answer (score 0):

They're both right, and DCL works fine in Java from 5 on.

If you are expecting your program to produce the exact same output every time given the exact same input, and you are using DCL, you may want to seriously rethink what you are doing.  An awful lot can depend on who gets to the lock first--you're rolling a lot of dice.  Not good for an accounting app.

If your program involves balls bouncing off walls and each other, DCL may make a lot of sense.  It does work.  Synchronizing has to be a bit slower than non-synchronizing even without contention, so why do it if a simple `if` can prevent it?  And if 100 threads pile up on a synch statement when the needed object already exists, that has to be a lot slower.

Answer (score 0):

The keyword "synchronized" that generates memory barrier full fences does not mean DCL could work properly. Let's take the following code as example:

```
public static Runnable getInstance()
    {
        if (null == instance)    //1
        {
            synchronized (Runnable.class)
            {
                if (null == instance)
                {
                    instance = new Runnable(); //2
                }
            }
        }

        return instance;
    }
```

We know that JVM will follow many steps when construct an object. We focus 2 important steps here:
First, JVM malloc the memory for this object. The value of member-variables in this object has defaut value for now. Second, JVM calls  method and assigns the user-specified value to the member variables.

That means thread A may get a partitially-constructed instance in code 1 (in the middle of the code 1 and code 2) . Although "synchronized" generates memory barrier full fences, there is no [happen-before](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/jls9.pdf) guarantee in code 1 and code 2. Memory barrier fences take effect during synchronized code block. Code 1 is outside the synchronized code block.